# Android Load Cache Only is not working. Show WebView offline

Tags: android, caching, webview, android-webview, offline-caching

I'm trying to show some webpages via webview without connecting to the internet. 
I'm getting a Null-Pointer Error if there is no connection to the internet. If there is a connection it is working. So I think it's something with

```
webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ONLY);
webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.de");
```

Please help me. I already checked if the AppCachePath is correct with getCacheDir(); 
Thanks a lot

```
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAppCacheMaxSize(1024*1024*8);
        webView.getSettings().setAppCachePath("/data/data/de.app/cache");
        webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);


        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
              @Override
              public void onReachedMaxAppCacheSize(long spaceNeeded, long totalUsedQuota,
                           WebStorage.QuotaUpdater quotaUpdater)
              {
                    quotaUpdater.updateQuota(spaceNeeded * 2);
              }
        });





ConnectivityManager cm =
(ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if(cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected()== true)
        {
            webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
            webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.de");
        }
        else{
            webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ONLY);
            webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.de");

        }
```

---

```
11-05 12:46:20.213: WARN/dalvikvm(15681): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b180)
11-05 12:46:20.213: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15681): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
11-05 12:46:20.323: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15681): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{de.webstest/de.webstest.webbrowser}: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-05 12:46:20.323: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15681):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2496)
11-05 12:46:20.323: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15681):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
11-05 12:46:20.323: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15681):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
11-05 12:46:20.323: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15681):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
11-05 12:46:20.323: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15681):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-05 12:46:20.323: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15681):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-05 12:46:20.323: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15681):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
11-05 12:46:20.323: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15681):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-05 12:46:20.323: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15681):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
11-05 12:46:20.323: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15681):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:862)
11-05 12:46:20.323: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15681):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
11-05 12:46:20.323: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15681):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-05 12:46:20.323: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15681): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-05 12:46:20.323: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15681):     at de.webstest.webbrowser.onCreate(webbrowser.java:87)
11-05 12:46:20.323: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15681):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
11-05 12:46:20.323: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15681):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
11-05 12:46:20.323: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15681):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! If you find a response is helpful, please up vote it. If the response successfully answers your question, please click the green check mark next to it to accept the answer. Also please look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask for advice on how to write a good question

Comment: What' the null pointer exception you're getting? What does it say in the logcat?

Comment: Hi, so nice of you that you help me. So here is the Log: 
WARN/dalvikvm(15681): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b180)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15681): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15681): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{de.webstest/de.webstest.webbrowser}: java.lang.NullPointerException
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15681): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2496)

Comment: Where is line 87 in your code?

Comment: if(cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected()== true)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of two things is happening. Either `cm` is null or `cm.getActiveNetworkInfo()` is returning null. I'm guessing it's `cm.getActiveNetworkInfo()`. If I'm right, then changing

```
if(cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected()== true)
```

to

```
if(cm.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null && cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected() == true)
```

should fix your problem.